# popToRootViewControllerAnimated causing the app to crash when the device orientation changes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, poptoviewcontroller

I am working on a navigation based project.

To get from A to B,I do this :

```
First *firstClass=[[First alloc] initWithNibName:@"first" bundle:nil];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstClass animated:YES];
```

Then from B to C, I do this:

```
 Second *secondClass=[[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondClass animated:YES];


Now, in C, I do this,trying to get back to A:

- (IBAction)goBack: (id)sender

{

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

By doing this I am successfully able to navigate back to A , but the app crashes when I

change the device orientation in A after moving back , where as it doesn't crash , when A is

loaded first time . Any help on this?

Comment: We need more informations to help you. Can you show your orientation methods' implementation please ?

Comment: I am jut doing this                                                 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:        (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 return YES;
}

Comment: Aren't you implementing new rotation methods ?

Comment: Since iOS 6, shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated, and there are new methods: supportedInterfaceOrientation and shouldAutorotate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17236/discussion-between-raj-and-isoftom)